# Which is faster: Intent.putExtra or SQLite query?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, database-performance

I want to know that which way is faster in performance between `Intent.PutExtra` or `SQLite query`.

- Should I attach all attributes of an object with the intent i.e, `ID, First Name, Last Name, Location, Phone Number` etc

**or**

- Should I attach only the `ID` of the object and in the 2nd activity I will make a query to the database.

Comment: Why don't you set a simple functional test and benchmark it yourself?

Comment: I thought may be someone can better explain that. :)

Comment: you can have cursor with in fraction of second, but getting data from cursor will take more time sometime depending on your no of colums

Comment: I am confused because i have read in a book that SQLite is faster than Java.

Comment: your intent extra is faster..

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, message passing using `Intent`s is going to be faster than any kind of disk I/O, which is what a SQL query would be doing inevitably. That's not to say that in all scenarios this will always be true, which is why doing some benchmarking yourself would be helpful, since it would show in your scenario and for your implementation which way works better.

If you only have a few items that need to be passed from one `Activity`/`Service` to another, using `Intent`s for message passing works well. But for large amounts of data or for persistence across device boots, etc, databases are the way to go.